# Checking Filter Condition in Another Data Extension in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

In the Marketing Cloud parent BU level, to which our external data comes in, we have 2 data extensions: one is "Customer_Data" and the other is "Master_Consent".

Our goal is to "download" the entire Customer_Data DE to a country-based child business unit, based on the criterion "Country" which exists only in the second DE - "Master_Consent DE".

Now, we have 2 matching columns between those 2 DE: "Global_ID" and "Address_ID". What is important is that we have multiple records with the same "Global_ID" and "Address_ID" data existing in the "Master_Consent" table as they relate to different types of permission channels.

Whereas in the "Customer_Data" we have another unique Primary Key, which is the "Customer_Key" (it does not exist in "Master_Consent").

Long story short, when we try to do a join SQL query on "Global_ID" and/or "Address_ID" to check for the "Country" criterion, logically, Marketing Cloud prompts the Primary Key violation error. The only way it works for us is if we do it via an "Overwrite" function and then filter on "Country".

My question here is the "overwrite" the way to go here (because we did get the mirrored data in the child DE in the end) or is there a better way to do this?

Here's the code we used for joining the 2 DEs:

```
SELECT 

a.Customer_Key, 
a.Email,
a.Global_ID,
a.Address_ID,
a.Address_Type, 
a.City, 
a.State, 
a.Postal_Code, 
a.Phone, 
a.Fax, 
b.Country 

FROM CUSTOMER_DATA AS a 
INNER JOIN MASTER_CONSENT AS b ON a.Global_ID=b.Global_ID 
WHERE b.Country='GB'
```

Comment: What is your target DE? What is the Primary Key there?

Comment: In the target "Customer_Data_GB" data extension, the primary key is "Customer_Key"., as it is in the parent DE from which we want to "download" the data from.

Comment: Okay. since one customer can have more than one type of consent, it has to throw Primary key constraint error. You can try the query mode of 'Append'. Its basically upsert

Comment: Ok, but if the "child" DE is always a snapshot of the parent DE, based.on the country criterion, is it OK to use overwrite because it will run hourly?

Comment: Depends upon how you are using the Child DE

Comment: We will query the child DE and combine it with local DEs to create email audiences.